# Valgrind for macOS SIerra on i7 MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

How can I get Valgrind working on my mac? Mac specs: mid-2012 11" 2GHz i7 MacBook Air with macOS Sierra 10.12.5. FWIW, `brew install valgrind` fails to build, as well as these steps from Zed Shaw's "Learn C The Hard Way" ex4:

```
# 1) Download it (use wget if you dont have curl)
curl -O http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.12.0.tar.bz2

# use md5sum to make sure it matches the one on the site
md5sum valgrind-3.12.0.tar.bz2

# 2) Unpack it.
tar -xjvf valgrind-3.12.0.tar.bz2

# cd into the newly created directory
cd valgrind-3.12.0

# 3) configure it
./configure

# 4) make it
make

# 5) install it (need root)
sudo make install
```

Valgrind also fails after modifying the file valgrind-3.12.0/coregrind/m_main.c line 4061 from:
`#if defined(VGO_darwin) && DARWIN_VERS == DARWIN_10_10`
to:
`#if defined(VGO_darwin)`
(per http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/Unable-to-compile-on-Mac-OS-X-10-11-td57237.html)
...I was able to complete an installation of Valgrind (prior to changing m_main.c the `make` error'd out) but unfortunately, now the simple test recommended in the README file for verifying the install is failing:

> See if it works.  Try "valgrind ls -l".  Either this works, or it bombs out with some complaint.

The complaint:

```
$  valgrind ls -l
valgrind: mmap-FIXED(0x0, 253952) failed in UME (load_segment1) with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory).
```

I'm not sure what exactly this means, so it would be great if someone could help parse the "complaint" and suggest a means to get a successful install of or alternative to Valgrind on macOS Sierra.

FWIW: per [Valgrind's website announcement](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html):

> 20 October 2016: valgrind-3.12.0 is available. This release supports: X86/Linux, AMD64/Linux, ARM32/Linux, ARM64/Linux, PPC32/Linux, PPC64BE/Linux, PPC64LE/Linux, S390X/Linux, MIPS32/Linux, MIPS64/Linux, ARM/Android, ARM64/Android, MIPS32/Android, X86/Android, X86/Solaris, AMD64/Solaris, X86/MacOSX 10.10 and AMD64/MacOSX 10.10. **There is also preliminary support for X86/MacOSX 10.11/12, and AMD64/MacOSX 10.11/12.** For more details see the [release notes](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html).

...and [release notes](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html):

> Preliminary support for MacOS 10.12 (Sierra) has been added.

---

Per this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43431715/5225057 I have also tried the following,

```
svn checkout -r 16297 svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk
cd trunk
curl https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=105218 > patch.txt
svn patch patch.txt
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

and am left with:

`valgrind: mmap-FIXED(0x0, 253952) failed in UME (load_segment1) with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory).`

---

UPDATE per thiagoveloso's answer:

[image: MacPorts Install Success]

```
$  man port
$  port version
Version: 2.4.1
$  sudo port install valgrind
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for valgrind
--->  Fetching archive for valgrind
--->  Attempting to fetch valgrind-3.12.0_0.darwin_16.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/valgrind
--->  Attempting to fetch valgrind-3.12.0_0.darwin_16.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/valgrind
--->  Attempting to fetch valgrind-3.12.0_0.darwin_16.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/valgrind
--->  Fetching distfiles for valgrind
--->  Attempting to fetch valgrind-3.12.0.tar.bz2 from http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/valgrind
--->  Attempting to fetch valgrind-3.12.0.tar.bz2 from https://distfiles.macports.org/valgrind
--->  Verifying checksums for valgrind                                               
--->  Extracting valgrind
--->  Applying patches to valgrind
--->  Configuring valgrind
--->  Building valgrind
--->  Staging valgrind into destroot
--->  Installing valgrind @3.12.0_0
--->  Activating valgrind @3.12.0_0
--->  Cleaning valgrind
--->  Updating database of binaries
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
$  valgrind --version
valgrind-3.12.0
$  valgrind ls -l
valgrind: mmap-FIXED(0x0, 253952) failed in UME (load_segment1) with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory).
```

---

UPDATE:
per http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html valgrind 3.13.0 has improved support for macOS 10.12... hopefully this will be a workable solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650338/valgrind-on-macos-sierra#51623185 (hint: $ `brew install valgrind` should work now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the June 15, 2017 release of valgrind 3.13.0, I am able to install and make use of valgrind on macOS Sierra (10.12.5). As a base case, I can successfully evaluate a very basic `valgrind ls -l`. I will be continuing to evaluate this build of valgrind as I complete the exercises in ZS's LCTHW.

Of note, I installed with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and have not (yet) tested installation with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or per a `curl` download, `md5` checksum, `tar` unpacking, `./configure`, `make` and `make install`.

per http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html:

> Release 3.13.0 (15 June 2017)
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> 3.13.0 is a feature release with many improvements and the usual collection of bug fixes.
>
> This release supports X86/Linux, AMD64/Linux, ARM32/Linux, ARM64/Linux,
>   PPC32/Linux, PPC64BE/Linux, PPC64LE/Linux, S390X/Linux, MIPS32/Linux,
>   MIPS64/Linux, ARM/Android, ARM64/Android, MIPS32/Android, X86/Android,
>   X86/Solaris, AMD64/Solaris and **AMD64/MacOSX 10.12.**

---

UPDATE
Valgrind is unsupported thus far on macOS High Sierra (up through 10.13.3)

Answer (score 1):

Are you stuck to Homebrew? Otherwise you can install [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) and just type:

> $ sudo port install valgrind

"Preliminary" support for macOS 10.12 has been added in version 3.12.0: [Valgrind.org](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have never used Macports. Do u have a working Macports install of `valgrind` on Sierra?

Comment: Yes I do. It installs and works just fine on my 2012 13" Macbook Pro under Sierra 10.12.5.

Comment: swEEt - thanks! Will give it a go when I am back in front of my lappy :)

Comment: Please see my edit, the installation was successful but valgrind is non-functional.

Comment: Yeah, I can reproduce your issue. Apparently I was very luck to use Valgrind on Sierra to debug a GIMP error, because it seems to be on the the very few applications that are currently supported -- see this comment by Valgrind's author Louis Brunner: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=365327#c12. So I guess you'll have either to wait a little bit more until Valgrind works ok for Sierra or find an alternative - perhaps Instruments?

Comment: Thanks... so far Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on a persistent boot USB or in Oracle's Virtual Box make for an environment where I can use valgrind.